# transforming recursive function to iterative in C

Tags: c, function, math, recursion, iteration

I need to an iterative function but I can only think about It as recursive

```
int f(int m,int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return m;
    if (m == 0)
        return n;
    return f(m+1, n-1) + f(m, n-1) + f(m-1, n-1) + f(m-1, n);
}
```

The problem is 3rd case as I said I can only think It recursively. I'm using C.

Comment: Can you describe what it is supposed to do?

Comment: It was just a math function that made me do in college exam , since they(teachers)arent posting the answer and I couldnt find by myself Im asking.

Comment: How is it stated?

Comment: @Shiro98: Your indentation needs some work. Well-formatted code attracts better answers.

Comment: Missing close bracket

Comment: It looks like there may be an analytical way to convert that function to something much simpler, but the *general* technique for converting a recursive function to an iterative one involves using an explicit stack to store state.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it depends on the recursion, for example tail recursive function is just a for loop (without stack); compiler are able to optimize them. There is a lot of such...

Comment: @JohnBollinger what about an example of that use of the stack

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, the *general* technique uses a stack (and it looks like this function needs one if it cannot be analytically reduced).  That a subset of recursive functions can be reimplemented iteratively without a stack does not change the nature of the general case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I probably misinterpreted your comment, I apologize for that

Comment: @Shiro98, if you saw this problem on an exam, then presumably your coursework covered the topic.  What, then, is the nature of your confusion?  We are neither a coding service nor a tutorial service, but we would like to address your underlying uncertainty if we can.

Comment: @Shiro98 beware that using a stack doesn't make the transform non recursive, it's a lure. Everywhere you need a stack means that you are using recursion. Disguise the explicit recursive call with a stack is of no interest (except if you need to understand what compilers do).

Comment: The function has overlapping subproblems, so it can be solved with a dynamic program. In this program, calculate one line after another (`f(m, ...)`) by simple accumulation of the previous values until you arrive at the desired position.

Comment: This function looks like a good candidate for memoization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide more details on the  Nico Schertler's idea, what you actually need is to compute values in diagonal order (because there is `m+1` in the formula). To make this more clear, let's introduce another function `g` such that

```
g(k, n) = f(k-n, n)
```

or to put it otherwise

```
f(m, n) = g(m+n, n)
```

And now let's re-write the recursive formula for `f` in term of `g`:

```
g(m+n, n) = g(m+n, n-1) + g(m+n-1, n-1) + g(m+n-2, n-1) + g(m+n-1, n)
```

or

```
g(k, n) = g(k, n-1) + g(k-1, n-1) + g(k-2,  n-1) + g(k-1, n)
```

and now you can see that here both `k` and `n` never grow so you can calculate `g(k,n)` if you only have all the values for two previous rows i.e. `g(k-1, i)` and `g(k-2, i)` + previous values in the current row.

If you put that into code you may get something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int m,int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return m;
    if (m == 0)
        return n;
    return f(m+1, n-1) + f(m, n-1) + f(m-1, n-1) + f(m-1, n);
}

int f2(int m, int n) {
    // covers bad cases such as m = n = 0
    if (m == 0)
        return n;
    if (n == 0)
        return m;
    int buf1[m + n + 1];
    int buf2[m + n + 1];
    int buf3[m + n + 1];
    int* curLine = buf1;
    int* prevLine1 = buf2;
    int* prevLine2 = buf3;
    // init first two lines with f(0,0), f(1,0) and f(0,1)
    prevLine1[0] = 0; 
    curLine[0] = 1;  
    curLine[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= m + n; i++) {
        // cycle buffers to avoid dynamic allocation for each line
        // curLine -> prevLine1 -> prevLine2 -> curLine
        int* tmp = prevLine2;
        prevLine2 = prevLine1;
        prevLine1 = curLine;
        curLine = tmp;
        curLine[0] = curLine[i] = i;  // f(0,i) and f(i,0)
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            curLine[j] = curLine[j - 1]  // m+1, n-1
                    + prevLine1[j] //m-1, n
                    + prevLine1[j - 1] //m, n-1
                    + prevLine2[j - 1]; //m-1, n-1
        }
    }
    return curLine[n];
}

int main()
{
    for(int n = 0; n < 6; n++)
       for(int m = 0; m < 6; m++) {
           int fv = f(m,n);
           int f2v = f2(m,n);
           printf("n = %d, m = %d, f = %d f2 = %d\n", n, m, fv, f2v);
       }

    return 0;
}
```

See [online demo](http://tpcg.io/Ue9r85) that shows that ouptut of `f` and `f2` is the same.

---

**Update** (simpler code)

Actually you don't need to go diagonally. Yes there is dependency on `m+1` but for `n` dependency is only for `n` and `n-1`. So it is enough to make the outer loop by `n` (rather than `m`) and just go in the inner loop up to `m+n-i` (rather than just up to `m`) and then you'll need only one previous line of values of `f`. The code goes like this

```
int f3(int m, int n){
    // covers bad cases such as m = n = 0
    if (m == 0)
        return n;
    if (n == 0)
        return m;
    int buf1[m + n + 1];
    int buf2[m + n + 1];
    int* curLine = buf1;
    int* prevLine = buf2;

    // f(i, 0)
    for (int i = 0; i <= m + n; i++)
        curLine[i] = i;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        // swap buffers to avoid dynamic allocation for each line
        int* tmp = prevLine;
        prevLine = curLine;
        curLine = tmp;
        curLine[0] = i; // f(0, i)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n + m - i; j++) {
            curLine[j] = curLine[j - 1] //m-1, n
                    + prevLine[j + 1]   //m+1, n-1
                    + prevLine[j]       //m, n-1
                    + prevLine[j - 1];  //m-1, n-1

        }
    }

    return curLine[m];
}
```

Updated demo with both `f2` and `f3` is [here](http://tpcg.io/dJ0k8k)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack that keeps a pair of integers (m,n) where every time you pop an element from your stack, you push back the followings.If either m or n was zero, then instead of pushing back the followings, you add m or n (depending on whichever was zero) to your running sum.

```
(m+1, n-1) 
(m, n-1) 
(m-1, n-1) 
(m-1, n)
```

Once your stack is empty, your running sum will be the answer. Despite this being equivalent to your recursive approach, you are better of with dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic programming as others have suggested.

First, create a big enough matrix in the stack which will store the intermediate values that will be reused, e.g.:

```
int matrix[20][20];
```

Then, think about which values you will need to compute the general solution. For instance, if you are requested `f(4, 2)`, the values that will be accessed are:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 # # # # # # #
1 # # # # # #
2 # # # # #
```

After that, think about how you can populate all those values of the matrix in the fastest way possible, ending up in the requested solution at `(4, 2)`.

This is the kind of performance you can expect:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                  Time           CPU Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------
f_original/1/1             9 ns          9 ns   72315573
f_original/8/1            69 ns         69 ns   10191593
f_original/1/8        337200 ns     337086 ns       1840
f_original/8/8     272417747 ns  272221086 ns          2
f_stack/1/1                9 ns          9 ns   80751042
f_stack/8/1               51 ns         50 ns   12440282
f_stack/1/8           243803 ns     242299 ns       2779
f_stack/8/8        177525517 ns  177187353 ns          5
f_memoization/1/1        229 ns        229 ns    3681680
f_memoization/8/1        255 ns        254 ns    2457598
f_memoization/1/8        517 ns        517 ns    1116021
f_memoization/8/8       1161 ns       1159 ns     554004
f_dynamic/1/1              7 ns          7 ns   90095265
f_dynamic/8/1             16 ns         16 ns   41905352
f_dynamic/1/8             52 ns         52 ns   11358252
f_dynamic/8/8            128 ns        127 ns    5244860
```

Explanation:

- `f_original`: The function as you posted it.
- `f_stack`: The approach suggested by @basak. This is a valid answer to the question, since it does not use recursion (i.e. you provide your own stack instead of using the one provided by the function calls).
- `f_memoization`: Same as the original, but with memoization. Not a valid answer, since it is still recursive.
- `f_dynamic`: The dynamic programming approach.

As you can see, most gains come from the memoization, but running through the matrix instead of using recursive calls makes it an order of magnitude faster.

Afterwards, you can optimize further. For instance, if you don't plan to reuse the intermediate values, you can avoid keeping all the matrix -- instead, keep the last two rows, as @SergGr points out:

```
f_optimized/1/1            8 ns          8 ns   76327765
f_optimized/8/1           16 ns         15 ns   42463467
f_optimized/1/8           44 ns         43 ns   12702290
f_optimized/8/8           90 ns         89 ns    7176011
```

Even more, if your `int` is small enough (e.g. 32-bit), then you can simply pre-compute most of the values -- there are only `399` values for `m >= 3` that fit on a signed 32-bit integer, so you can keep them all. This is roughly `1.5 KiB` of data, and then you have a `O(1)` function that returns in `2 ns`.